Openpyxl - How to read the same cell in all of the sheets within a file?
I'd like to loop through all the sheets in my Excel file, read the content of cell B2 from each sheet, and print it out. Later, I plan to set conditions based on the string value of that cell.

The cell of interest is B2: I would like to print the three different student names, which are Roberto, Miquel Angelo and Leonardo.
My current piece of code is only printing 'Leonardo', (Sheet_3).

# Importing modules
import openpyxl as op
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

# Defining the file path
file_path = r'C:/Users/machukovich/Desktop/stackoverflow.xlsx'

# Load workbook as openpyxl
reference_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)

# We will mantain the workbook open
wb = reference_workbook.active

# Getting the sheetnames as a list using the sheetnames attribute

sheet_names = reference_workbook.sheetnames
print(sheet_names)

# Loading the file into a dictionary of Dataframes
dict_of_df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None, skiprows=2)

# Reading up the B2 cell for later use:
student_name = wb['B2'].value
for sheet_names in dict_of_df:
    print(student_name)


Below, you can find snapshots of the Excel file to further clarification.





Just doing the following should be all you need.
Included list to add names to as well.
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file_path = r'C:/Users/machukovich/Desktop/stackoverflow.xlsx'
reference_workbook = load_workbook(file_path)

names_list = []
for sheet in reference_workbook.worksheets:
    student_name = sheet['B2'].value
    print(f"Student Name: {student_name}")
    names_list.append(student_name)

print(f"List of Names: {names_list}")

As noted by @Max888
If you are importing load_workbook from openpyxl, you don't need to specify that module in the command, i.e.;
openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path) should just be load_workbook(file_path)
